# NVD3 sunburst chart not working

Tags: angularjs, rendering, nvd3.js, sunburst-diagram

I try to use the nvd3 sunburst charts. Therefore I wanted to try to place the example in my website first. Unfortunately it doesn't render even if the data is there.

Here is my HTML content:

```
<div class="container-fluid full-height" ng-controller="sunburstChartController">
    <h1>OVERVIEW</h1>

    <nvd3 options="options" data="burstdata" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>

</div>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('my-controllers').controller('sunburstChartController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'sunburstChart',
            height: 450,
            color: d3.scale.category20c(),
            duration: 250
        }
    };

    console.log($scope.options);

    $scope.burstdata = [{
        "name": "flare",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "analytics",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "cluster",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                            {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                            {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                            {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "graph",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                            {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                            {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                            {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                            {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "optimization",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "animate",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
                    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
                    {
                        "name": "interpolate",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
                            {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
                            {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
                            {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
                            {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
                            {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
                            {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
                            {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
                            {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
                    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
                    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
                    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
                    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
                    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
                    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
                    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
                    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "data",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "converters",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
                            {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
                            {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
                            {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
                            {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
                    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
                    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
                    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
                    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
                    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "display",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
                    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
                    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
                    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "flex",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "physics",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
                    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
                    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
                    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
                    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
                    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
                    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
                    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "query",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
                    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
                    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
                    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
                    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
                    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
                    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
                    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
                    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
                    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
                    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
                    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
                    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
                    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
                    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
                    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
                    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
                    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
                    {
                        "name": "methods",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "add", "size": 593},
                            {"name": "and", "size": 330},
                            {"name": "average", "size": 287},
                            {"name": "count", "size": 277},
                            {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
                            {"name": "div", "size": 595},
                            {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
                            {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
                            {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
                            {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
                            {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
                            {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
                            {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
                            {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
                            {"name": "max", "size": 283},
                            {"name": "min", "size": 283},
                            {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
                            {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
                            {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
                            {"name": "not", "size": 386},
                            {"name": "or", "size": 323},
                            {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
                            {"name": "range", "size": 772},
                            {"name": "select", "size": 296},
                            {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
                            {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
                            {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
                            {"name": "update", "size": 307},
                            {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
                            {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                            {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                            {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
                    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
                    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
                    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
                    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
                    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
                    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
                    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
                    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
                    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "scale",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
                    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
                    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
                    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
                    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
                    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
                    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
                    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
                    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
                    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "util",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
                    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
                    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
                    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
                    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
                    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
                    {
                        "name": "heap",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
                            {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
                    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
                    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
                    {
                        "name": "math",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
                            {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
                            {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
                    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
                    {
                        "name": "palette",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
                            {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
                            {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
                            {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
                    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
                    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
                    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
                    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "vis",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "axis",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
                            {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
                            {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
                            {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
                            {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "controls",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
                            {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
                            {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
                            {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
                            {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
                            {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
                            {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
                            {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
                            {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
                            {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
                            {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "data",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
                            {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
                            {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
                            {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
                            {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
                            {
                                "name": "render",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                                    {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                                    {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                                    {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                                ]
                            },
                            {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
                            {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
                            {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "events",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
                            {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
                            {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
                            {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "legend",
                        "children": [
                            {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
                            {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
                            {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "operator",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "distortion",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                                    {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                                    {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "encoder",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                                    {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                                    {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                                    {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                                    {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "filter",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                                    {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                                    {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                                ]
                            },
                            {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
                            {
                                "name": "label",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                                    {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                                    {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "layout",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                                    {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                                    {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                                    {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                                    {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                                    {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                                    {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                                    {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                                    {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                                    {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                                    {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                                    {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                                    {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                                    {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                                    {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                                ]
                            },
                            {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
                            {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
                            {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
                            {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
                            {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }];
}]
);
```

The console log here, displays the options in the console correctly and there are no dependency errors, therefore I conclude it can't be any issue with dependencies.

For completeness, here the index.html:

```
    <html ng-app="seriesAnalyzer">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <title>Series Analyzer</title>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script> <!-- or use another assembly -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/appstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/x-search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/orders.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/edit.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-project-name">
                    <div>T<span>he</span> B<span>ig</span> B<span>ang</span> T<span>heory </span>A<span>nalyzed</span></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="navbarCtrl" id="navbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">


                   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Overview <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#overview">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Configuration Tables <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/full-config-tables">Overall</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/season-config-tables">Seasons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/episode-config-tables">Episoden</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Speakers <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/speaker-overview-table">Overview Table</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/speaker-single-view">Single Speakers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


    <div ng-view>

        Test

    </div>


    <!--Angular-->
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js"></script>

    <!--Libs-->
    <script src="assets/libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-file-saver.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--App-->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/configTableController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/speakerTableController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/speakerSingleViewController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/navbarCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/sunburstChartController.js"></script>

    <!--Directives-->
    <script src="app/directives/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/directives/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="app/directives/d3BarDirective.js"></script>

    <!--Services-->
    <script src="app/services/services.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/tabService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/userService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/d3Service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/currentSelectedSpeakerService.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can download the JS files from the below location and use. I had the same issue with the files from NPM, I have replaced them with below files It worked.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js
https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js
```